# Poner un limite de registros a una tabla en mysql o MariaDB INSERT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, trigger

Veran me han pedido que mi tabla Empleados tenga un limite de registros (300), usando mysql. Deseo que al hacer un insert este no se haga si en la tabla empleados ya estan completos los 300 registros. Lei por ahi que puedo hacer un rollback, al intentarlo en mysql en un trigger me da un error, el que no puedo usar el rollback implicita o explicitamente.

hay alguna manera de realizar esto de poner un limite de registros en una tabla (En usuario puede eliminar, editar etc, dentro de ese limite de 300), espero ser claro, sino me disculpan, se los agradezco

esto hice el trigger, es de prueba, lo hice segun otro post, igual inserta el registro pese a que puse como limite un 2

```
BEGIN
    SET @LIMI = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE ESTADO = "ACTIVO");

    IF (@LIMI > 2) THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Penalty values can only be raised, not lowered!';

    
    END IF;

END
```

esta es la tabla empleados
[image: introducir la dintroducir el código aquíescripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por favor edita y coloca tu código como texto, anexa además el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: Pero en el caso que mostras, tu count no es mayor a 2...

Comment: Pero para hacer un rollback, ¿deberías tener el autocommit deshabilitado no? y en todo caso iniciar el insert con `start transaction`, es así como lo estás haciendo?

Comment: Mi count es 2. tengo 2 empleados activos. Busco que solo pueda insertar unicamente 300 empleados activos

Comment: Te apoyas en algún lenguaje para hacer el registro, por ejemplo `PHP`?. Por que de ser así, es mucho más fácil controlar la cantidad de registros que se pueden insertar.

Comment: si, es en laravel @DjCrazy

Comment: Pero tu codigo dice @LIMI > 2... no dice 300.. dice 2...

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu comentario, puedes apoyarte en `PHP` (*con `Laravel` en tu caso*) para lograr el objetivo.

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo de la lógica que usaría. Si te sirve, adaptas la propuesta a tu código.

Antes de registrar un nuevo usuario haces una validación similar a la que propones en tu pregunta:

```
$usuariosActivos = "SELECT COUNT(OID) CANTIDAD FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE ESTADO = 'ACTIVO'";
```

Luego comparas el valor de esta variable con tu límite de 300 y decides si haces o no el registro:

```
if($usuariosActivos['CANTIDAD'] == 300){
  #Devuelves un mensaje de error en el que indicas que no es posible realizar el registro 
  #porque supera el límite de usuarios permitidos y omites el registro
} else {
  #Lanzas el script para insertar el registro
}
```

Si no soy claro en el planteamiento de la propuesta, házmelo saber en los comentarios.

**Edición:** gracias a @gbianchi por su recomendación.

Puedes hacer esta validación desde el front de tu app...

La validación es similar, puedes inactivar el botón de agregar nuevos registros cuando existan 300 usuarios activos. De igual manera debes conservar la validación en el back al enviar los datos para evitar casos como el que expone @gbianchi, en el que un usuario retoque el código desde el navegador para habilitar el botón.

La desventaja de usar esta opción, es que si otro usuario desde otro punto de trabajo inactiva uno de los 300 usuarios tu botón seguiría inactivo hasta que refresques el navegador.

Tienes múltiples soluciones, solo debes elegir la que más se adapte a tu necesidad sin intervenir directamente en la BD.

Éxitos!

Comment: la segunda opcion no es buena porque facilmente podes reactivar el boton tocando el js. Ademas, podrias simular la llamada que hace el boton por mas que este desactivado. Las validaciones en el front son solamente una ayuda, y la validacion en el back debe existir siempre

Comment: @gbianchi, concuerdo contigo, por seguridad siempre deben existir las validaciones en el back, lo que pretendo es darle a entender al OP que tiene varias alternativas para llegar a solucionar su caso. Por ejemplo, puede tener una combinación de ambas opciones y de esta manera, evitar que el usuario llene un formulario con datos que no se van a registrar. Puede hacer la validación al abrir la pagina y mostrar una alerta en caso de estar en el límite de 300...

Comment: una combinacion de ambas si.. solo el front no.. eso no queda claro en tu post.. ;)

Comment: Entiendo, ya lo edito...

Comment: os agradezco chicos, perdonen por contestar tarde. ME han servido las respuestas, es bueno validar eso en el back. Pero lo hice el en front con un if ta cual mencionas, con las etiquetas blade

Comment: Si la respuesta fue útil, te invito a aceptarla y/o votarla. De esa manera ganamos reputación ambos. Éxitos!